# Can't invert operators order

Tags: c++, operators

On my class on c++ I have write a class and I have override the plus operator.

this is the prototype :

```
Var operator + (const Var& var);
```

Why the IDE tell me that this is correct :

```
Var a = 3;
a + 5;  //  Correct
```

But this not?

```
Var a  = 3;
5 + a;  //  error
```

what i need to do for can sum a integer with my object on this order?

Comment: http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/operator_overloading.html -- basically, you need a free function `operator+`.

Answer (score 2):

The reason is that operators as a member functions are not symmetric. Object of the class you define operator in should be always on the left side.

What you need is - you should put your operator function outside of the class.

```
Var operator+(const Var&, const Var&);
```

And if you need to access private fields declare it as a friend function.

Answer (score 1):

> what i need to do for can sum a integer with my object on this order?

It will need to be a non-member:

```
Var operator + (const Var& var1, const Var & var2);
```

This allows type conversions to be applied to either operand, not just the right-hand one.

If it needs access to the class's privates, then it will also need to be a friend.

Comment: But then i need to delete this override:
Var operator + (const Var& var);
and replace it whit that :
Var operator + (const Var& var1, const Var & var2);
?

Comment: Where i need to declare that override? not in class declaration?

Comment: @pava91: If it's a friend then it can be in the class definition; otherwise, in the surrounding namespace.

Comment: Only on class definition if it's fiend? i can't write the prototype into class and function on cpp file :S

Comment: @pava91: Yes, you can do that if you prefer. A friend needs to be declared in the class; it's up to you whether to implement it there, or outside.

Comment: I can't do it correct. I have write on pastebin the actual class definition. [link](http://pastebin.com/SBLjSNzx) .
I need to replace all override with friend function? AND then on cpp file what is the syntax for declare the function?

Comment: Now i can do that :
Var a = 2, b = 3;
a += b + 5;
BUT NOT 
a += 5 + b;

Answer (score 1):

For the latter you'd need a free function

```
Var operator + (int, const Var& var);
```

The other form suggests your Var has implicit conversion, so

```
Var operator + (const Var& lhs, const Var& rhs);
```

might be even better.

remember that member functions never allow conversions on the lhs.

Answer (score 0):

When you overload an operator as a member function, the operator is not symmetric. The reason is that the overloaded operated is invoked on the first argument. So if you have overloaded `+` operator as a member function and write `a1+a2` it translates to `a1.operator+(a2)`. This means that a1 has to be a member of the class.

If you want symmetric functionality, you should implement it outside the class and if it needs access to private data members of the class declare it as a `friend`.

`Var operator+(const Var& first, const Var& second);`